# Getting constant error of - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is one of my components in the project named `Posts.jsx` which displays all the posts received from a component, but as soon as I render the component the page goes blank showing :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').
```

Even if I write posts?. maps... it doesn't work. Please help me with this.

```
import Post from "../post/Post";
import "./posts.css";

export default function Posts({posts}) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="posts">
          
          {posts.map((p) =>{
            {console.log(p)}
            <Post post = {p} />
          })}
      </div>
    </>
    
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your prop `posts` is `undefined`. Check what value you pass to the component and make sure this is an array.

Answer (score 0):

It happens if `posts` is fetched by the consumer of the component from an API trough a request for example. While the data is being fetched `posts` may be `undefined` depending on how you implement it. A solution is to check with `?` ([Optional Chaining Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)). Like so:

```
import Post from "../post/Post";
import "./posts.css";

export default function Posts({posts}) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="posts">
          
          {posts?.map((p) =>{
            {console.log(p)}
            <Post post = {p} />
          })}
      </div>
    </>
    
  );
}
```

If you are still getting the error it means `posts` is not an array, make sure it's one when defining it, change it and also when passing it to the component.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you imported
`Post` with a capital `P` and you are trying to map `post` with a small `p`
Use this code to correct it

```
import Post from "../post/Post";
import "./posts.css";

export default function Posts({posts}) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="posts">
          
          {Posts.map((p) =>{
            {console.log(p)}
            <Post post = {p} />
          })}
      </div>
    </>
    
  );
}
```